# How to adjust this query to get the biggest value in column using active record in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I would like to make an active record query for getting the biggest value of column **order**
where parent_id equals $parent_id.

So far I have this:

```
function get_biggest_order($parent_id)
    {
        $result = 0;
        if(!empty($parent_id)) 
        {
            $this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
            $result = $this->db->get('pages');
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

But as you see I am getting all rows instead of just one where the order collumn has the biggest value e.g. 14.

How to do that?

I was thinking about something like:

```
$this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
$this->db->where('order', something is the biggest);
$result = $this->db->get('pages');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `order_by`:

```
$this->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
$this->db->order_by('order', 'desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
$result = $this->db->get('pages')->row();
```

Comment: Isn't it a little overkill? Sure I have only maybe 10 records, but hat if I have like 5000? Isn't it possible to use some `where` clause instead of order everything and then pick only the first row?

Comment: @Derfder - No, this is not overkill it is the only sensible way to do it. If you index the `order` column it will be fast even if you have 100.000 records.

Comment: btw. what does `get('pages', 1)` mean? Is it something to include limit in get ?

Comment: @Derfder - You could add a `limit` to limit the number of rows returned.

Comment: Yes. It's the same as `$this->db->limit(1);`.

Answer (score 1):

The `select_max()` method is what you should be using. Much faster and more self-explanatory.